# Android Material Signature element with a listview

Tags: android, listview, toolbar

I have a layout that consists of a Cover image (hero image) a toolbar and a listview.

On the new Material design guideline (like seen on this checklist: [tangible surfaces](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/material-design-on-android-checklist.html)), when I scroll the list view, the cover image should go behind the toolbar and the listview, then the toolbar should scroll to the top.

on the Google i/o 2014 app, you can see this feature under the session activity.
The problem is that they are using a ScrollView that have everything inside it.

How can you do the same thing with a listview instead?

[EDIT] : after the release of the new Design support library (http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), the solution is using a coordinator layout with a recyclerview. But thanks to @Endor anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FrameLayout` as a root, add an `ImageView` as the first child for the cover and then add a `ListView` as the second child.

Like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#CA8500"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

</merge>
```

Obviously the ListView will be blocking the ImageView, so the trick here is to add a transparent header to the ListView with the same height as your cover ImageView.

Then as user scrolls up the ListView, the ImageView will be covered by the real content of the ListView.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is it the "oficial" solution?

Comment: No, this is not the official solution, just my own implementation. One (major?) down side with this approach is that whatever lies beneath the Listview header will not respond to touch events because the Listview will capture them all.

Comment: I want to point out that the solution is based on Roman's implementation [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/). Look at the last section on "other visual effects". In his example, a Space is placed ahead of the actual content of the ScrollView. Then I used the same technique and put a Space as header for ListView.